# Confusion related to context sensitive grammar creation

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I was reading this wikipedia article for generating grammar. They have mentioned that for generating null string in the grammar we can have a rule

$$S \rightarrow  \lambda$$

only if $S$ doesn't appear on the right of any production rule.

However in some examples like the following

$L(G) = \{ a^nb^n : n \ge 0 \}$. It has rules like

$$S \rightarrow aSb$$ 
$$S \rightarrow ab$$
$$S \rightarrow \lambda$$

Here $S$ is appearing on the right. So how come they are using $S \rightarrow \lambda$ rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s minor sloppiness. Change the productions to

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to aTb\\
&S\to ab\\
&T\to aTb\\
&T\to ab\\
&S\to\lambda\;,
\end{align*}$$

and you have essentially the same grammar written in a form that meets the requirement.

**Added:** There are really two different notions involved here. Let $\Sigma$ be the set of terminal symbols and $\mathscr{N}$ the set of non-terminal symbols, and let $S$ be the initial symbol. A context-sensitive production is one of the form $\alpha A\beta\to\alpha\gamma\beta$, where $\alpha,\beta\in(\Sigma\cup\mathscr{N})^*$, $\gamma\in(\Sigma\cup\mathscr{N})^+$, and $A\in\mathscr{N}$; it gets its name because the replacement of $A$ by $\gamma$ occurs only in the context $\alpha\_\beta$. A monotonic production is one of the form $\alpha\to\beta$, where $\alpha,\beta\in(\Sigma\cup\mathscr{N})^*$ and $|\alpha|\le|\beta|$; it gets its name from the fact that the length of the string in a derivation is monotonically non-decreasing. It’s a theorem that a language has a grammar consisting entirely of context-sensitive productions if and only if it has a grammar consisting entirely of monotonic productions. Call such languages *purely context-sensitive* for the moment.

Unfortunately, these productions don’t allow us to generate any language that contains the empty word. We’d like to make the context-sensitive languages a superset of the context-free languages, some of which **do** contain the empty word. To do this, we allow the production $S\to\lambda$ provided that $S$ does not appear on the righthand side of any production. It’s a sort of one-time exception to allow us to generate the empty word; it’s not intended to let us generate anything else that wasn’t already able to be generated. In other words, we want to generate only purely context-sensitive languages and languages that would be purely context-sensitive if they didn’t include the empty word.

The reason for not allowing $S$ to appear on the righthand side of any production is that if we **don’t** make that restriction, we can write grammars that generate languages that would **not** be purely context-sensitive even if we threw away the empty word. In fact, we could generate every language that can be generated by any formal grammar whatsoever. In terms of the Chomsky hierarchy, we could generate not only all of the type $1$ languages, but also all of the type $0$ languages. The restriction ensures that we really do generate only the type $1$ languages, i.e., those that are purely context-sensitive and those that would be purely context-sensitive if they didn’t include the empty word.

Some grammars that violate the restriction are easily seen to be equivalent to grammars that do not violate it; that’s the case with the one that you asked about, as I showed by replacing it with the grammar above. When that can obviously done, the grammar is sometimes sloppily referred to as a context-sensitive grammar, even though technically it isn’t.

Comment: Yeah thats fine I guess. But I didn't get how $S \rightarrow \lambda $ spoils it. I mean why is it that if S appears on the right we cannot use $S \rightarrow \lambda$

Comment: @rajan: If you allow $S\to\lambda$ with $S$ on the right, a production like $A\to S$ effectively allows $A\to\lambda$. With that capability you can get Type $0$ formal languages as well as context-sensitive one.

Comment: But we already have $S \rightarrow \lambda$ which makes it type 0 isn't it. I mean taking your example grammar in the answer.

Comment: @rajan: My example as I rewrote it is context-sensitive. Of course every context-sensitive grammar is also type $0$, but that isn’t what I meant in my previous comment: I meant that you could get *all* type $0$ langages, as well as the context-sensitive ones.

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you elaborate more with some examples pls. That will help me understand it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Like the production rule $S \rightarrow \lambda$ is a production rule of type 0 isn't it because it is dereasing I mean if I use it then it decreases the right part so it is like type 0 right.

Comment: @rajan: I added a lot of explanation; I hope that it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But can you please give an example grammar, where adding the rule $S \rightarrow \lambda$ with S being present on the right makes it generate type 0 grammar as well. I mean an example of a language generated with type 0 grammar and that generated by a type 1 grammar. So if we add the rule $S \rightarrow \lambda$ this type 1 grammar can also generate type 0 language. Just a real example. So that it is clear to me. I mean lets say we add $S \rightarrow \lambda$ rule then it will generate a few more strings, which make it type 0 language as well. HopeI am clear